# BLE GATT max value and service update

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am trying to write a value onto one of the BLE beacon characteristics, but probably hitting some size limits. I didnt manage to find **clear** answer on how big the value can be so I am hoping someone here knows it.

The value I am trying to write is:

```
RU5fODAxNDEyYWEzNWEzNDY3NmZiOWM3M2QyZjA2ZjA3ZjI1ZjM5OGNmZTY3MzIz
```

64 bytes.

This gices me back error

```
Unable to write on return
```

Which doesn't tell me anything.
I know I can write string because I can write "Hello World" in it.
In some articles people say the value can be max 512 bytes, in some they say it can be max 20 bytes at once - while testing none of those proved to be true.

**Second part of a question**

Can I write new service with characteristics on bluetooth? I have phone and I have separate piece of HW - beacon, can I add new service to it over the air?

I imagine not, so - how can I rewrite this piece of HW with my own structure of services and characteristics?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

- Beacon is from Estimote
- I tried writing to all characterictics that are available, couple of them could write "Hello World" one of them being:

`

```
Service b9402000-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d

Characteristic b9402002-f5f8-466e-aff9-25556b57fe6d
```

Unfortunately they just updated their beacon firmware and made proper mess in their GATT specs, so it takes a bit more time for me to test them all and create my own specs table to follow. But just a quick test reveiled what I have written above.

I am aware that their characteristics probably won't let me do what I want, hence the question "can I add services"

Comment: You should add more specifics to your questions so we can help provide an answer.  What kind of BLE Beacon device is this?  Which characteristic are you trying to write to that accepts "Hello World"?  Understand that each characteristic has its own max length.

Comment: @davidgyoung I updated the question. It was really meant to be a general question, for anyone searching in future for this to find an answer. There is need for clear answer on how much and what can you write into characteristics. Already talked to a couple of people working with beacons, none of them could give me a clear answer.

Comment: ATT MTU is 23 bytes so you should split in chunks the value you want to send. Depending on the characteristic, it may accept a smaller fixed sized data (eg 16 bytes or 2 bytes) so you might get an error when writing data that does not match the expected length, you could try different data lengths. Also look for characteristics that allow notifications, they might send data back as response to the write operations.